# class-dump -H throw Unknown load command: 0x00000032

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to parse a Mach-O file so I use class-dump:

```bash
class-dump -H xxx.app
```

But it throw an error:

```
class-dump[7747:13147879] Unknown load command: 0x00000032
```

And only generate one .h file: `CDStructures.h`

```
//
//     Generated by class-dump 3.5 (64 bit).
//
//     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2013 by Steve Nygard.
//
```

My class-dump version is 3.5.

Comment: Try dsdump by delek selander https://github.com/DerekSelander/dsdump